# Can't get web html code: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Tags: c#, vb.net, webclient, downloadstring

My problem is that I can't get specific website html code and I get this error: 
'System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

My code is simple:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://isbnsearch.org/isbn/");
            MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);
        }
```

When I try using other website like Google everything works perfectly, but with this website I can't reach it.

Is there any solution to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well as you dont have access to isbnsearch.org, so you can just catch the error and avoid your app break down, but can not solve it.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                 string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://isbnsearch.org/isbn/");
                 MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                 MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying having access to website? I mean from my perspective it's just like other websites like google.com

Comment: @Tadas I mean that accessing that content is forbidden, if the site trying to download was his, he could solve it, but not that doesn't, it is an error in his code but access denial of the server.

Answer (score -1):

Found solution to get over this error:

```
        string url = "https://www.isbnsearch.org/";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    MessageBox.Show(result);
                }
            }
        }
```